# Count pattern and matching lines simultaneously

Tags: shell-script, grep

I want to count the occurrence of a pattern per line and also get the last matching line number

So for counting patterns I would use

```
grep -c pattern file
```

and for last matching line number

```
grep -n pattern file | cut -d : -f 1 | tail -1
```

Is there any way by which I get both the results by greping only once? The file I am working with is large and I need to iterate this for several patterns, so I would like to avoid greping twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
awk '/pattern/ {last = NR; count++}
     END {printf "Last: %s\nCount: %d\n", last, count}' < file
```

Beware that `awk` patterns are *extended* regular expressions (with slight differences with `grep -E` ones wrt backslash).

You could also use only one `awk` invocations for all your patterns:

```
awk '!patterns_finished{patterns[$0]; next}
     {
       for (p in patterns) if ($0 ~ p) {
         last[p] = NR
         count[p]++
       }
     }
     END {
       for (p in patterns)
         printf "%s: count=%d last=%s\n", count[p], last[p]
     }' patterns.txt patterns_finished=1 file
```

(assuming `patterns.txt` contains the list of patterns, one per line).